# Npm install directly from Github Error: ENOENT

Tags: github, npm

I'm running an example from [build-nodejs-npm-installation-package-scratch](http://decodize.com/javascript/build-nodejs-npm-installation-package-scratch/). Instead of uploading to npm repository I'm putting it on Github and trying to download it via npm instead. I run `npm install git+https://github.com/t2wu/replaceme.git` and got the following:

```
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod '/private/tmp/node_modules/replaceme_tim/replaceme.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.2.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "git+https://github.com/t2wu/replaceme.git"
npm ERR! cwd /private/tmp
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! path /private/tmp/node_modules/replaceme_tim/replaceme.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /private/tmp/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I have a package.json in there, I cannot figure out what is wrong.

EDIT: I can install Express OK, but I can't install my practice module

Comment: Run cmd with admin rights, I tried it while ionstalling phonegap, explained here goo.gl/r9lJnx

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to missing permissions or unlinked files while npm was working. This topicc is also seen at github, [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3664).

Try running with admin perms.

Comment: I can install Express. But I can't install the practice module. So something wrong with my module?

Comment: @huggie maybe. Not sure